# Swift optional variable assignment with default value (double question marks)

Tags: swift

So I was trying to do

```
let foo = dict["key"] as? String ?? "empty"
var bar = some_func(string: foo!)
```

and XCode 6 complains that
`Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is 'String'`
on the second line.

If I change the first line to

```
let foo: String? = dict["key"] as? String ?? "empty"
```

the error goes away.

Is this some kind of flaw or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The nil-coalescing operator `a ?? b` is a shortcut for

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

it returns either the left operand *unwrapped* or the right operand. So the type of `foo` is `String` and the second line should be

```
var bar = some_func(string: foo)
```

without the exclamation mark because `foo` is not an optional and can't be unwrapped.

(If you change the first line to

```
let foo: String? = dict["key"] as? String ?? "empty"
```

then the result of the right hand side is wrapped into an optional string again, and needs
to be unwrapped in the second line. It makes the error go away, but this is probably not what you want.)

Comment: If you are giving a default value "empty" in case you wouldn't be able to cast it, why you declare foo as String? optional? It will never be optional as it will either be casted to a String coming from dict["key"] or will get the default String value "empty". 

I would just remove the `: String?` part and leave it as `let foo = dict...`

Comment: @denis_lor: The `let foo: String? = ...` is already present in the question. Note that my explanation ends with “... this is probably not what you want.”

Answer (score 4):

Your `foo` will be a `String` not a `String?` because the nil coalescing operator `??` will either unwrap your conditional cast if it is `.some` (resulting in a `String`) or it will use `"empty"`, which is also a `String`.